# Incorrectly calculated measure in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a table Sales

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o75Yh.png)

Table Calendar:

```
Calendar = CALENDAR(DATE(2023, 01, 01), MAXX('Table',[Date]))
```

I need to calculate the amount in the "product" column per month and total.

Starting from July 2023, i need to calculate  the amount in the **"product"** column,  only where the **"status"** is "delivered" and "shipped" .

Before July 2023, i  need to calculate the amount in the column **"product"** for all status

My measure:

`measure1 =
VAR d=MAX('Table'[Date])

var jul=
CALCULATE (SUM('Table'[Product]),
'Table'[Status]="DELIVERED" || 'Table'[Status]="SHIPPED")

var nojul=CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Product]))

var result=IF(d>=DATE(2023,07,01), jul,  nojul)

return result`

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4De3c.png)

The amount in the "product" column is calculated correctly for each month. But the total is wrong. The total is 73, but i should be 84.

This is because the total is only calculated for the status "delivered" and "shipped".

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, for the total there is no date and so it will use the max date of the whole table, ie well after July 1st. So for the total it is using `jul` for every month. The total of the matrix isn't calculated by adding the totals in the table, instead, the measure is calculated for the table without 'row' context'

So, try re-doing your measure like this:

```
measure2 = 
  var jul = DATE(2023, 7, 1)
  var totJulPre = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Product]), 'Table[Date] < jul)
  var totJulPost = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Product]), 'Table[Date] >= jul && 'Table'[Status]="DELIVERED" || 'Table'[Status]="SHIPPED")
  RETURN totJulPre + totJulPost
```

This will work for each row, and also for the whole table (ie the visual total)